# linux mint 11 64 bit Citrix Client

Tags: linux-mint, 64bit

Does anyone have Citrix Client 64 bit client working on Linux Mint 11?
Been searching for a while and applying several suggestions without success.
I've even attempted to get the 32 bit version of Citrix client to work, also without success.

Answer (score 1):

As of Oct. 5 2011 (8 days after this question was posted) [Citrix provides a 64-bit client](http://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=2316611&productId=1689163) in .deb and .rpm formats.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the client do you need? I found this [link](http://martinwebster.eu/2011/02/26/how-to-install-citrix-xenapp-client-on-linux-mint/) which may be of some help. This [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo#A64-bit) to an ubuntu package may also help.